# Meaning of red plus sign in FreeBSD ports configuration screen

Tags: freebsd, freebsd-ports

Maybe a bit of a noob question, but I can't find it anywhere (I googled it, and I've tried the handbook, but I might have missed it):

When I install a port and the port asks for configuration options, I can make a selection of the different options. The standard options are selected. However, in front of some of the standard and of the other options there's a red plus sign. What is the meaning of the plus sign in the configuration screen?

Answer (score 4):

They are options, where you haven't previously configured anything.

This is useful if with an update a new option is added and you wonder why the config dialog pops up again.